# Unsigned Right Shift operator works as the normal right-shift operator, why?

Tags: java

When I use the Unsigned Right Shift (Logical Shift) operator in java, I get the same result as the normal right-shift operator would give.
my code is:

```
        byte b1 = -99; // 01100011
        byte result = (byte) (b1 >>> 6);
        String  str = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(result & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

The preceding code produces the same output which is -13 with both of `>>` and `>>>` operators, what is the reason behind that and how to resolve it?

Comment: The short answer is that `>>` and `>>>` are integer operations.  And the "resolution" depends on what you actually want to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `byte` is a signed type in Java, and bit shifting (whether normal or with sign extension) is done in `int`, so before performing the shift, the value of `b1` is implicitly cast back to int (which preserves sign). (As an aside, the value -99 is not 01100011, it is 1001 1101 in `byte` and 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001 1101 in `int`).

With `b >> 6` (or `-99 >> 6`), the value is -2 (1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110), with `b >>> 6` (or `-99 >>> 6`) the value **in `int`** is 67108862 (0000 0011 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110). However, when you then cast to `byte`, this last value becomes -2 as well (1111 1110).

What you need to do is make sure you get the unsigned value of the byte as the integer value before shifting:

```
byte result = (byte) ((b1 & 0xFF) >>> 6);
```

Which results in 2.

Comment: but this work with '>>' also, so why do we need '>>>' ?

Comment: @HusenPatel - Consider the case where the number you are shifting is an `int`.  Then `>>` and `>>>` will give different results for -ve numbers.  That's why they are needed.

Comment: @HusenPatel When shifting int or long, it works as you expect. See my example `-99 >> 6` is -2, while `-99 >>> 6` is 67108862. The type byte (and short as well) are slightly degenerate in that they are promoted to int for all operations (see [Java Language Specification, section 4.2.2. Integer Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2)).